# How to display the remote sql instances of a particular machine using SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

i wnat to display the Remote machine SQL instances using SMO .How to do this one.

Suppose i am using the machine machine 1 from this machine i want to display the remote machine(ex machine2) SQL instances using smo how to this ??

i am using SmoApplication.EnumerateSqlServers(true)

this dispalys only the local instances. false displays the network instances and

SmoApplication.EnumerateSqlServers(string x) displays the only that named instaces of a local machine.

But when i give machine name it shoud display the instances installed on that machine how to do this using SMO objects??

Help me ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you post your question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097010/how-to-get-the-list-of-sqlinstances-of-a-paricular-machine

Answer (score 0):

you can't. smo uses UDP ping to check for sql server. plus this only works inside your domain (no vpn) and on non firewalled sql servers.